# Windows 8 Fails to install with corrupted graphics

Tags: windows, graphics, nvidia-geforce, dell-dimension

I am trying to install ***Windows 8 Pro Upgrade*** via the ***download method*** on an older PC (07-08).  It is a ***Dell Dimension E521*** but it has been upgraded with a 3.0 Ghz Dual Core AMD Processor, 120 GB SSD, and 4 GB of RAM.  The Windows 8 upgrade assistant did not detect any issues or concerns with upgrading other than I don't have DVD software installed.

The system install Windows 8 but on the *first boot, corrupt graphics are present*.  Eventually, the monitor will go into sleep mode and then roll back to Windows 7 Pro X64 which runs fine.

I wouldn't be upset over not being able to install Windows 8, but I already paid for the software since I thought there would be no issues upgrading.

The Graphics card in the system is the ***Geforce 7300LE*** and it has the latest NVidia drivers for Windows 7 loaded.

I saw this solution which is similar to my problem:
[Corrupt graphics during Windows 8 installation](https://superuser.com/questions/501812/corrupt-graphics-during-windows-8-installation?answertab=active#tab-top)

However, I have downloaded Windows 8 and I am not sure how to go about modifying the install that resides somewhere on the hard drive.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

**Update**
I tried to install OEM driver from Dell, but they only have drivers for Vista x64. This is not compatible with my current setup.  I am currently running Nvidia Geforce 306.97 WHQL which lists the 7300 LE as a supported device.

**Update 2** 
I uninstalled the Nvidia drivers and cleaned them out, the system installed the WDDM drivers.  I attempted to upgrade once again with the same end result.

I did notice that the link on my desktop allows me to create installation media.  Is this something I need to pursue?

Comment: When you downloaded, the Upgrade Assistant would have given you an option to create installation media (USB or DVD ISO). If you didn't select that, how are you re-running setup? From a link on the desktop?

Comment: Uninstall the nvidia driver before you upgrade.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your responses.  Karan: I am am not given an option for installation media.  I am re-running the setup from the link on the desktop.  Moab: I will give that a try, but I don't think it will work, the first time I tried to upgrade I did not have the NVidia drivers, it was a fresh Win 7 install to upgrade to 8.  I thought that maybe I needed to upgrade the drivers before the install so I did that and I got the same error/result.